# How to Read data from USB serial port using node js and print to webpage

Tags: node.js, serial-port, usbserial

I am using RS232 to USB connector, I getting reading to hyper-terminal from Interfacing Machine. I  want to print data on web page.

Comment: You'll need a desktop program which reads data from the serial port and then sends it to the web application

Comment: Thank you for reply. Please anybody have node.js program for read data from USB serial port and print to webpage. I got blog of this but I facing lots of error [https://designswow.blogspot.com/p/reading-data-from-serial-port-with_15.html]

Comment: Your link doesn't work

Comment: P.s. not sure why you would want to use nodeJS for that anyway - it's mainly a server side framework and you need something client side which runs easily in a desktop machine. (I'm assuming your device is connected to a desktop machine, and not the server where your web application is running, although you didn't actually mention the exact scenario)

Comment: I am sending link again https://designswow.blogspot.com/p/reading-data-from-serial-port-with_15.html

Comment: Ok. If you're getting errors you'll need to show your version of the code and tell us what the error messages are. (Please edit your question to show us, do not put code or errors into these comments.) We can't guess what your specific issue is.